# Workaround to pass "256" as a parameter using a byte

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I'm making a class which contains a private array that I am using to cache calculated values. I want to limit the number of elements to **256** at maximum, since that is the maximum number of elements an indexer that uses a `byte` index can access; I also need the number to be fairly small, so this works.

However! It must be passed as an argument in the constructor, since the client code would determine just how big it would be. But, if I take a `byte` as an argument, the maximum is 255; I understand why and how this is, but I cannot figure out the best workaround.

```
public class Spritesheet
{
    private Rectangle[] _values;
    public Spritesheet(byte spriteCount)
    {
        _values = new Rectangle[spriteCount]; // But this needs to store 256 values at most...
    }
}
```

I could make it a **byte?** and if it's null, use 256 elements, but that seems arbitrary (although it would certainly work). The other alternative I can see would be using an **int** and clamping the value somehow, but exposing it as an int might give the user the wrong intent of the code.

**EDIT:** Changed "spritesToIndex" to "spriteCount" to make it clearer. And for what it's worth, this is the interface I made that I'm implementing:

```
public interface ISpritesheet
{
    Texture2D Texture { get; }

    byte Sprites { get; }
    byte SpritesPerRow { get; }

    Point Size { get; }
    Point Spacing { get; }
    Point Offset { get; }

    Rectangle this[byte index] { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The other alternative I can see would be using an **int** and clamping the value somehow

Using `int` is exactly what I would do.

> but exposing it as an int might give the user the wrong intent of the code.

So make the intent so explicit that the user cannot possibly get the wrong idea:

```
public class Spritesheet
{
  public Spritesheet(int spriteCount)
  {
    if (spriteCount < 0 || spriteCount > 256)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("spriteCount", "Number of sprites must be between 0 and 256 (inclusive)");
    // ...
  }
}
```

Even if the user at any point gets the idea that `spriteCount` can be 1000, that idea will fade *very* quickly after trying it.

I renamed `spriteToIndex` in response to Richard Schneider's comments, who quite understandably interpreted the meaning of the variable name differently. The word "Index" in it could be read as suggesting that the value must be an index, rather than the total number of sprites.

Comment: Being explicit here uncovers an interesting conclusion: this accepts 257 valid inputs, not 256, so the input has to be something bigger than `byte`.  However, that's only the case if 0 is actually a legal value.  If 0 is not actually legal, then RichardSchneider's answer has the advantage of making it compile-time impossible to pass in an illegal value.

Comment: @Joe: This is exactly what prompted the question in the first place. I had originally intended for 0 to be a legal value, because an array of 0 elements is valid C#.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you have your constructor take the count as an `int` argument, and make it obvious through documentation and parameter naming that this should not exceed 256. You can guarantee that by throwing an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` for values that exceed that range.

Personally, I'm more used to supplying range parameters as `ints` anyway -- using a `byte` here feels unorthodox, at least to me.

Comment: This isn't unorthodox at all - the type exists for a reason, and there's no restriction on using it as a parameter. It might be uncustomary for you to use it, but there's no code smell associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

1. your initialiser for `_values` is wrong.  You should add 1 `spritesToIndex`.
2. the constructor args to `Rectangle` is an `int`.

So the following should work:

```
_values = new Rectangle[(int)spritesToIndex + 1];
```

@hvd has a good point.  The constructor should accept an `int` type and just `throw ArgumentOutOfRange`.

Comment: If `spritesToIndex` is the total number of sprites that need to be indexable, and the first sprite index is 0, then `new Rectangle[spritesToIndex]` is correct. But your answer gives an interesting alternative. Changing `spritesToIndex` to `maxSpriteIndex` (and add one like you do now) would allow keeping it as a byte.

Comment: @hvd, your answer is better if we rename the arg to `maxSprites`.  I was just hacking.

Comment: Oh! Now I see how you read it. I read "spritesToIndex" like the OP probably intended, which is "sprites to index" (where "to index" is the infinitive), but it can also be read as "spritesTo index" ("index of spritesTo"), and that would indeed lead to your answer. Will edit my answer, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, edited to make my code intent better. I also added my interface I'm implementing; with this, it should be obvious that all the Rectangle objects will be generated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The C# `Byte` type is an 8-bit container which can hold values in the range 0 to 255, which means it has a 256-value capacity. If your application needs to track 256 indexed items, this will suffice because the first element of an array is the 'zero-th' element (i.e. foo[0] is the first element).

However, if you actually need to track 256 discrete items where they have a positive identifier value and zero is not appropriate as the first value, a `Byte` will not suffice. You will instead have to use a type with a larger capacity such as `Short` or `Int`, and add bounds checks in your code to limit their value range to 1-256.

Comment: I will be using 0, the issue is that I cannot accept a `byte` as a parameter and create a 256-element array from that (as Byte.MaxValue is 255, not 256, despite there being 256 possible values).

Comment: Yes you can - 0-255 is 256 values (or, if you prefer, foo[0] - foo[255] is an array of foo that contains 256 elements).

Comment: Right, but I can't use a byte as a parameter to declare an array with 256 elements, since... the highest possible value is 255, even though there are 256 unique values.

Comment: OK, you can't pass the actual value 256 - but if you pass 255 and instantiate the array with that value, you get an array with 256 elements. So the value you pass as the parameter is one less than the number of elements you want in the array.